# Dutch Highly Skilled Migrant permit vs EU Blue Card

Tags: working-visas, netherlands, blue-card

I'm currently holding an EU Blue Card in Poland. By the time I move to Netherlands it will exceed 18 months. My future employer ready to support application to Dutch Highly Skilled Migrant permit, but not an EU Blue Card.

Is there any comparison of Dutch HSM visa vs EU Blue Card?

Which one may be more preferable and why?

Is it possible to apply to and hold both of them at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I found out after a talk with expatriate consultancy company in Netherlands:

HSM permit and EU BC are very similar in general.

**Pros of HSM permit**: application is cheaper, it requires less documents and usually issued faster. The minimum required salary is also less by ~700 eur/month. There are less requirements (and probably fees) for employer as well, that's why employers mostly prefer to deal with HSM permit.

**Pros of EU BC**: if you have been holding EU BC for more than 18 months, you need to wait less than 5 years to be able to apply for citizenship. If you decide to move to another EU country your card owning term will preserve.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to apply to and hold both types of permit at the same time.

Comment: Deleted my post as contained wrong information